# Pentaho kettle transformation - skip 1st line in csv file

Tags: file, csv, transformation, pentaho, kettle

I am working on a csv file and format of csv file is very similar to :

FIRST LINE---FIRST LINE---
deptno,dname,loction
10,ACCOUNTING,NEW YORK
20,RESEARCH,DALLAS
30,SALES,CHICAGO
40,OPERATIONS,BOSTON

Now I want to skip 1st line (), when this file will be read by csv input or text input step.
2nd line is header.

Is there any method or transformation to achieve this requirement?

At this moment, I am CSV File input but I don't find.
I'm using Pentaho 5.0.1

PS : Sorry for my english

Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the order of the columns vary? Or in other words: do you actually need the column header line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the header rows on the tab *Content* of the text input component. See the following screen shot.

[image: Content tab of text input component]

Comment: Thanks for your help
But it's not working.

The header is just for the columns names.

But my first line is not a header. It is a useless line. I would like to skip or delete this line.

They is no transformation for that?
Or
I can not wait to be in the second line to start playing the file?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that Kettle can distinguish between the two cases.

Answer (score 3):

You could put your strange string in the fields tab ("FIRST LINE---FIRST LINE---") as it would be a regular header. Then you split all the rows with a split fields step.

Otherwise you could use the "Load file content in memory" step and check, in the content tab, the rownum field. Then you can use the "filter rows step" to skip the first one. After this you can put everything in a new csv file, which should be correct.

[image]

[image]

[image]